# IHttpActionResult difference between returning item, Json(item) and Ok(item)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

In ASP.NET WebApi 2, what is the difference between the following:

```
public <IHttpActionResult> GetItem(Guid id)
{
    // ... code ..., Item result = ....
    return result;
}

public <IHttpActionResult> GetItem(Guid id)
{
    // ... code ..., Item result = ....
    return Json(result);
}


public <IHttpActionResult> GetItem(Guid id)
{
    // ... code ..., Item result = ....
    return Ok(result);
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This code returning `result` won't compile, as `result` doesn't implement `IHttpActionResult`...

```
public <IHttpActionResult> GetItem(Guid id)
{
    // ... code ..., Item result = ....
    return result;
}
```

Returning `Json()` always returns HTTP 200 and the result in JSON format, no matter what format is in the Accept header of the incoming request.

```
public <IHttpActionResult> GetItem(Guid id)
{
    // ... code ..., Item result = ....
    return Json(result);
}
```

Returning `Ok()` returns HTTP 200, but the result will be formatted based on what was specified in the Accept request header.

```
public <IHttpActionResult> GetItem(Guid id)
{
    // ... code ..., Item result = ....
    return Ok(result);
}
```

Comment: but  when I use  Json  I get same results that I get with ok and there is not any difference in the results that I see in the success condition of ajax.They both are formatted objects.would you please explain more about your experience in difference of results?

Answer (score 1):

Just an addition to previous explanations:

The return types for your fuctions are: `IHttpActionResult`

Therefore the expectation is for the method to return a `IHttpActionResult` which is an interface for `HttpResponseMessage`. The `HttpResponseMessage` has useful properties such as Headers, Content, and Status code.

Therefore, `Ok(result)` returns a `HttpResponseMessage` with `Ok` status code and the contents, which in this case is the result. Meanwhile, `Json(result)` converts the object to json format, aka serialization, and that gets placed as the content in the `HttpResponseMessage`.

The best thing about a web api with ASP.NET is that it creates simple ways to pass the Http Responses through abstraction. The worst thing, is it takes a bit of understanding before actually using the relatively simple methods.

[Here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization) is more info about serilization and json

[Here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/action-results) is more about info about IHttpActionResult